# On the definition of Lie algebra bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, vector-bundles

I have a question in the definition of Lie algebra bundle:

In Wikipedia, the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_bundle#:%7E:text=Any%20Lie%20algebra%20bundle%20is,not%20be%20true%20in%20general.&text=and%20deform%20it%20by%20the%20real%20parameter%20as%3A&text=Lie%27s%20third%20theorem%20states%20that,might%20fail%20to%20be%20Hausdorff.) of Lie Algebra bundle says:

A Lie algebra bundle $\xi = (\xi,p,X)$ is a vector bundle in which each fibre is a Lie algebra and for every $x \in X$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$, a Lie algebra $L$ and a homeomorphism
$$
\phi:U \times L \to p^{-1}(U)
$$
such that $\phi_x: x \times L \to p^{-1}(x)$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism.

---

*My Question:*

Does the Lie algebra $L$ depend on $x \in X$? i.e., does $L$ changes as $x$ changes, or it remains fixed?

Comment: Every fibre has to be isomorphic to a fixed $L$ but they aren't all the same in the sense that we can't in general write the bundle as a product $X \times L$. This is true for all fibre bundles

Comment: @Callum I think the question is about the Lie bracket on $L$, not $L$ as a vector space. To which the answer is, I believe: yes. For $U$ sufficiently small, all the Lie algebras will be isomorphic.

Comment: @Callum: Yes, the question is about the Lie bracket on $L$, not $L$ as a vector space. I have edited my question to add this point.

Comment: @QuaereVerum I did not refer to the vector space structure. By isomorphic I mean isomorphic as a Lie algebra. My point is that this idea should work in more generality. Loosely, a fibre bundle where each trivialising map $\phi$ gives isomorphisms (of whatever structure, Lie algebra, group, vector space,etc.) on our fibres with a fixed structure should imply that (over a connected manifold) all the fibres must be isomorphic to that fixed structure. As Andreas points out, this is different to just picking a structure on each fibre.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a matter of wording to me and I personally would not use a term like "Lie algebra bundle" without making clear what I actually mean. I often use the wording "locally trivial bundle of Lie algebras" to mean that there are local trivializations with values in the product with a fixed Lie algebra. In this case, the individual fibers are indeed all isomorphic to this modelling Lie algebra (at least on a connected manifold).

For the other concept, there is an obvious interpretation as a vector bundle $L\to M$ together with a vector bundle homomorphism $\Phi:\Lambda^2L\to L$ covering the identity map on $M$ such that for each $x\in M$ the value $\Phi_x:L_x\times L_x\to L_x$ satisfies the Jacobi identity. I would rather refer to this a "family of fiber-wise Lie algebra structures" on a vector bundle.